# How to check battery history in a text format on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, power-management, acpi, battery

I am using the command `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` and `acpi -V` to check the battery current status. It shows it has history and statistics.

How can I check the history?

I knew there are some apps which can produce a nice graph of the battery history, but that is not what I am looking for. I would like to see the history in a text log. I want to examine the text log with some scripts and editor to determine when the battery status changed etc..

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:**

If the question is not possible, how to monitor battery state change event? I need to record the battery information whenever the battery/ac state changes. So checking upower or acpi output at a interval time is not sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113490/where-does-gnome-power-statistics-get-its-data-from#comment134330_113505

All data is logged to `var/lib/upower/history-....dat`

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the battery status with `watch`.

Else, you can use `cat` to log the power status into a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. How can I use `watch` to monitor battery status change event?